# How to retrieve value from array nested in JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, multidimensional-array, nested

I would like to know how to access the value of "result 2" from my JSON object using jQuery or pure JavaScript.

```
var jsonarray = [{

title: "Kategori1",

  items: [{

    result: "Item1",
    //Nested array
    items2: [{
      //How to get the value of result2
      result2: "item1 item1"
    }],
  }, {

    result: "Item2"
  }, {

    result: "Item3"
  }]
}];
```

If I run `console.log(this.data.items[i].items2);`
I get:

```
[Object { result2="item1 item1"}]
[Object { result2="item4 item4"}]
```

...in the console, but after that I'm stuck.

I have tried with:

```
this.data.items[i].items2.result2; // Not working
```

Also with another loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < this.data.items.length; ++i) {
    this.data.items[i].result, // Gives me the result from the items array, working
        for (var items2 in this.data.items[i]) {

            var result = this.data.items[i]['items2'];
            console.log(result.result2); //Not working            
        };
}
```

Comment: check my answer with working demo

Comment: will proceed further, if you have any issues with my two solution2

Comment: What you posted is part of a Javascript object literal, not JSON. In JSON, all the property names need to be in quotes, and trailing commas aren't allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i already commented, you have trailing comma before end of square bracket. please remove to make your `JSON` valid.

Try like below.

#### Solution 1: Direct Access without iteration.

```
document.write(jsonarray[0].items[0].items2[0].result2);
```

#### Solution 2: Iterated Solution

```js
var jsonarray = [{
  title: "Kategori1",
  items: [{
    result: "Item1",
    //Nested array
    items2: [{
      //How to get the value of result2
      result2: "item1 item1"
    }],
  }, {
    result: "Item2"
  }, {
    result: "Item3"
  }]
}];

// Iterate jsonarray Array.
for(var i = 0; i < jsonarray.length; i++) {

 // Iterating Array Element: Items.
 var items = jsonarray[i].items;
 for(var j = 0; j < items.length; j++) {
  var itemsItem2 = items[j].items2;

  // Checking whether Item2 is exist and variable type is Array.
  if(itemsItem2 && itemsItem2.constructor == Array) {

   // Iterating Items items2.
   for(var k = 0; k < itemsItem2.length; k++) {
    document.write(itemsItem2[k].result2);
   }

  }
 }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply and for a good solution, i updated my post and got rid of the comma trailing.

Comment: Okay, this is all fine and dandy if you know the names and what level they're at. Is there a general technique for doing this if you don't know where in the structure this is? I need to retrieve a field that is nested 6-deep in one JSON object and compare it with the same field in another object nested 2-deep, and I need to make this general enough to just search any complex object for a particular field.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
this.data.items[i].items2[0].result2;
```

Answer (score 0):

`items2` is an Array and must be accessed by an index

```
this.data.items[0].items2[0].result2
```

Also, your JSON is formatted incorrectly. You have trailing commas.

```js
var data = JSON.stringify({
    title: "Kategori1",
    items: 
    [
        {
            result: "Item1",
            items2: [
            {
                result2: "item1 item1"
            }]
        },
        {
            result: "Item2"
        },
        {
            result: "Item3"
        }
    ]
});
var json = JSON.parse(data);

alert(json.items[0].items2[0].result2);
```

Comment: What he posted is a Javascript literal, not JSON. Trailing commas are allowed in Javascript.

Comment: @Barmar, notice that I converted his *"JSON"*  to actual JSON with the `JSON.parse(data);` line in my example

Comment: Why did you need to convert it to JSON in the first place? If you have an object, just access it.

Comment: @Barmar Good point.  Object => JSON => Object && access object || access object. I guess I just like mental ferris wheels

Answer (score 0):

My previous answer was written when you had actual JSON, but I am editing this to meet your criteria.

You have a JavaScript array, not JSON. To access item `result2`, you can execute this line of code:

```
console.log(jsonarray[0].items[0].items2[0].result2);
```

Since this isn't JSON, you do not need to reference the `data` object.